# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: ERROR in The given rootPath undefined is not a file of the program

Tags: angular, .net-core

I updated .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1 (first) and then angular version from 6 to 9.
After updating the .net core the app still working. Didn't see any issues. After I update the angular version I get an error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: ERROR in The given rootPath undefined is not a file of the program.
```

Anyone with this problem and get it solved?

Thanks!!

Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                      .UseIISIntegration()
                                      .Build()
                                      .Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>

                builder.AddFile(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName                = "Perfix-";            
                    options.LogDirectory            = "LogFiles";   
                    options.FileSizeLimit           = 20 * 1024 * 1024;     
                    options.Extension               = "log";
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit  = null;                

                }
                )
              )
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<>(appSettingsSection);


        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.jwtSecretKey);



        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));


        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);   
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DarwinContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnection"),
            sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<int>("SQL_TimeOut"))),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient);

         services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
        });


        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
       {
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
           options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
       });

        // create a Autofac container builder
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       builder.Populate(services);

        builder.RegisterModule<ServiceModule>();

        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }

    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }


     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Darwin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.2",
    "@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine": "^9.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.7.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx-populate": "^1.20.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "ESNext",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Update:

If I put in tsconfig enableIvy as false the error as gone.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  },
```

but the CSS not working properly.
What I should see:

[image: before]

and what I see now: (Seems that the float is not working.)

[image: now]

Comment: I have the same problem, any luck?

Comment: @spenf10 if you do the enableIvy then you can compile. The problem is the CSS.. you have to update the CSS.. bootstrap changed so there is things that doesn't work.. redo some CSS is needed..